# get row values to one column recursively (and doing combinations)

Tags: sqlite, pivot

I have one input table, it has dates and a fixed number of events. I need to create, from it, the list of events with date of occurrence, and the list of combined events and their occurrence.

Example:

**initial table:**

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    date DATE    PRIMARY KEY,
    e1   INTEGER,
    e2   INTEGER,
    e3   INTEGER
);

date       | e1 | e2 | e3 |
--------------------------
2017-02-04 | 2  | 1  | 26 |
2017-02-05 | 14 | 2  | 1  |
2017-02-06 | 1  | 3  |  2 |
```

**Output 1**

```
eventN | total | date1      | date2      |...|  date'N'
--------------------------------------------------------
 01    |  3    | 2017-02-04 | 2017-02-05 |...| 2017-02-06
 02    |  2    | 2017-02-05 | 2017-02-06 |...| (null)
...
 26    | 1     | 2017-02-04 |  (null)    |...| (null)
```

**Output 2**

```
CobineEventN | total | date1      | ... | date'N'
-----------------------------------------------------
  0102       |  2    | 2017-02-05 | ... | 2017-02-06
  0103       |  1    | 2017-02-06 | ... | (null)
  ....
  2526       |  1    | 2017-02-04 | ... | (null)
  ....
```

Limitations:

- this has to be done in SQLite.
- there is no limit for the dates (i.e. 'n' unique dates).
- the events, are a fixed list of (around)50 ids
- the *output* will be tables, one for each type of combination.
- the author SQL skills.

Comment: Doing this in SQLite alone is not possible.

Comment: @CL. not even output1?

Comment: Even Output 1 would require a custom number of columns, and SQLite has no mechanism to construct dynamic queries from within itself.

Comment: So @CL. , if I read you correctly, I have two choices, or I 'Python'it and I have the tables drawn from outside, or I 'Pivot'It and have to live with tables with a massive amount of columns and rows sparsely populated? 
Does the 2nd option have any advantage over the 1st?

Comment: What do you need the tables for? Aren't you accessing SQLite from a 'real' programming language anyway?

Comment: The output tables are for data manipulation facilitation (prep. work). There will be Python to do user interaction, I will also use it to build them. Thanks.

Comment: So when you have Python, where does the SQLite-only limitation come from? (Both outputs can be computed with SQL queries, but you have to construct the list of columns in Python or manually.)

Comment: Just from my ego.

Comment: I continued talking and realized that I was seeing the problem from the wrong point of view.
I posted my conclusions in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some talk with a teacher, he pointed out that my model was all wrong from start.
changing the table to:

```
REATE TABLE event (id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date date NOT NULL, event smallint unsigned NOT NULL);
```

*'id' is unnecessary

something like:

```
 Id     date     event
    31  2016-10-05  1
    44  2016-10-07  1
    32  2016-10-05  2
```

I could use a query like:

```
select A.event as nA, B.event as nB, C.event as nC, date
from event as A, event as B, event as C
where A.date = B.date
and B.date=C.date
and nC<>nA
and nC<>nB
```

and obtain the values needed.

```
    nA  nB  nC   date
    1   2   3   2016-10-05
    1   2   3   2016-10-07
    1   2   4   2016-10-07
...
```

Although the format is not exactly what I had imagined, the results work fine.
And I don't need to create any more columns for the rest of the project, just have to do the right queries.

BR